# How to create List of List in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a below list.

`['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'A_4', 'B_1','B_2', 'C_1', 'C_2', 'C_3']`

I need the output in below format.

`[['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'A_4'], ['B_1', 'B_2'], ['C_1', 'C_2', 'C_3']]`

I am very new to Python, is there any way to achieve the above output that it would be really helpful.

Comment: Does it mean that you want to group by the first letter?

Comment: What if it goes like `['A_1', 'B_1', 'A_2']`?

Comment: @SharimIqbal you shouldn't have edited the code like this without confirming from the OP. It could be that they meant variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved directly with a dictionary combined with a loop：

1. store each type of data in the form of "letter_", e.g. {"A_": ["A_1", "A_2"]}
2. Loop through each data in the list, if the type is not in the dictionary, create a list with the prefix type of this data, otherwise add it directly to the list of this type
3. Finally, directly convert the values of the dictionary into a list to achieve the requirement

```
category = {}
lst = ['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'A_4', 'B_1','B_2', 'C_1', 'C_2', 'C_3']
for item in lst:
    prefix = item.split("_")[0] + "_"    # Example of prefix values: A_, B_,...

    if prefix not in category:
        category[prefix] = [item]    
    else:
        category[prefix].append(item)

print(list(category.values()))
# [['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'A_4'], ['B_1', 'B_2'], ['C_1', 'C_2', 'C_3']]
```

Comment: Using `in` on a dictionnary search in the keys ? Or is it because theres no str value that contains the prefix ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` for that. This assumes that the input is sorted, as in your example.

```py
from itertools import groupby

lst = ['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'A_4', 'B_1', 'B_2', 'C_1', 'C_2', 'C_3']
output = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: x[0])]
print(output) # [['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'A_4'], ['B_1', 'B_2'], ['C_1', 'C_2', 'C_3']]
```

If for some reason you don't want to use `import` but only use built-ins,

```py
lst = ['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'A_4', 'B_1', 'B_2', 'C_1', 'C_2', 'C_3']

output = {}
for x in lst:
    if x[0] in output:
        output[x[0]].append(x)
    else:
        output[x[0]] = [x]
print(list(output.values()))
```

Note that with an input list of `['A_1', 'B_1', 'A_2']` the two approaches will result in different outputs.

Answer (score 1):

I provided a easily understandable way (but requires more lines than other advanced thecniques)

You can use `dictionary`, in particular, I used `defaultdict` here to set default value as a list ([]).

I grouped the list by first letter in a `for loop`, as follows:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

l = ['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'A_4', 'B_1', 'B_2', 'C_1', 'C_2', 'C_3']

group = defaultdict(list)

for item in l:
    first_letter = item[0] # saving items by first letter
    group[first_letter].append(item)

result = list(group.values())
print(result)
# [['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'A_4'], ['B_1', 'B_2'], ['C_1', 'C_2', 'C_3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code:

```
input = ['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'A_4', 'B_1', 'B_2', 'C_1', 'C_2', 'C_3']
```

Use below logic:

```
ls_a,ls_b,ls_c = [],[],[] # Declaring empty lists
for i in input:
if 'A' in i:
    ls_a.append(i)
if 'B' in i:
    ls_b.append(i)
if 'C' in i:
    ls_c.append(i)
output = [ls_a,ls_b,ls_c]
print(output)
```